# What format is the second parameter of eth_sign?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, json-rpc

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sign","params":["**", "0xdeadbeaf"],"id":1}
```

Here is an example

Ignoring the first parameter, what format is the second parameter?

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sign","params":["**", "hello"],"id":1}
```

Should I convert "hello" to hex and concatenate 0x?

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sign","params":["**", "0x68656c6c6f"],"id":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ethereum wiki](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sign), the second parameter is a keccak256 hash of the message, with the following format:

```
keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) + message)
```